# How can I write a function that relies on dynamic selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am writing a function to dynamically load jQuery UI accordian leaves with content. I know (think) the AJAX part works as I lifted it from another working AJAX loader I have, but the function as a whole does not work.

The code:

```
    function load_leaf(link){
    var link = link;
    $.ajax({
            cache : false,
            type : 'POST',
            async: false,
            url : 'includes/'+ link +'.php?'+ new Date().getTime(),
            dataType : 'text',
            data: {
                owner : '$user_id'
            },
            success: function(msg){
                $("#" + link).html(msg);
                console.log('Can\'t see me in Chrome, but ok in firefox !')
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log($.makeArray(arguments));
            },
            complete: function() {
                console.log($.makeArray(arguments));
            }

    });
};
$(function(){
    $('.accordian').click(function(){
        var link = this.getAttribute("link");
        load_leaf(link);
    });
});
```

For whatever reason this does not work. The break point seems to be this line
`$("#" + link).html(msg);`
Specifically the selector, as a hard coded selector works perfectly. The link variable is correctly filled i know this as i can alert the value correctly. The link is not the problem as i replaced the whole ajax function with a simple add class and it a still did not work, it also broke at the selector.

EDIT:
This is the div as printed by php:

```
<h3 class="accordian" id="'.$tab_id.'" link="'.$tab_link.'" >
 <a href="#">'.$tab_name.'</a>
</h3>
<div id="'.$tab_link.'"><p>Hi</p></div>
```

The html for the first one is:

```
 <h3 class="accordian" id="accordian_manage.php" link="accordian_manage.php" ><a href="#">Manage Images</a></h3><div id="accordian_manage.php"><p>Hi</p></div>
```

Comment: `var link = link;` What's the point of that if link is already defined?

Comment: Yeah, but keeping your code samples tidy and short are concepts of [SSCCEE](http://sscce.org). :)

Comment: Are you testing this on localhost or a server? Just wondering because of your `Can\'t see me in Chrome, but ok in firefox !` log.

Comment: Fabricio, i don't care at the moment, once it works i'll make it pretty. It is on local host.

Comment: Just to add a note, Chrome won't allow for null-origin ajax calls by default. And what do you expect to do with the code exactly? The problem is most likely due to your `id`/`link` having a period `.` in it, which makes jQuery assume you're looking for an element with `id="accordian_manage"` and `class="php"` I'd guess.

Comment: That might be it i will try, and report back.

Comment: That was it, please post that as an answer if you would like rep for a correct answer.

Comment: Ok, making an answer right away.

Comment: I've also added an workaround to my answer, in case you don't want to change all of your `link`s/`id`s saved in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID has a period `.` in it, which jQuery interprets as a chained class selector.

You can either change your link/IDs, or use this hack:

```
$("[id='" + link + "']");
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/983e3/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is with Jquery is not finding the div to load the msg..Post the accordion div so that i could give you the proper selector

Comment: What do you mean give me the appropriate selector? It is dynamic, not hard coded. Oh and the markup is posted.

Comment: Before setting the ID to the accordion remove .php from it .. and inside the success function remove .php from your link and use it as a selector, it should work good